# GIt , get latest commit hash of a specific branch merged in another

Tags: git, hash, version-control, merge, branch

Having a branch, i need to know the hash of the latest commit of another merged branch.

This is my specific situation:

**branch A** merged with commit X of **branch C**

**branch B** merged with commit Y of **branch C**

How can i find the hash value of commit X and Y ?

Is there a git command to retrieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose the one suite you teh best:

#### git merge-base

[`git merge-base`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base) is the command you are looking for

> *git merge-base* finds best common ancestor(s) between two commits to use in a three-way merge. One common ancestor is *better* than another common ancestor if the latter is an ancestor of the former. A common ancestor that does not have any better common ancestor is a *best common ancestor*, i.e. a *merge base*. Note that there can be more than one merge base for a pair of commits.

#### Manually find it from the log

`git log --decorate --graph --oneline --all`

This will display the fork points in the log so you can track the commit id of the branching.

---

#### Sample:

Given two commits A and B, ***`git merge-base A B`***
will output a commit which is reachable from both A and B through the parent relationship.

Comment: would be nice to have a "single-line" command to retrieve that value instead manually search it inside the log list

Comment: Then use the merge-base  its a single line command. Simply read the attached documentation link in the answer and you will see sample code.

Comment: thankyou! `git merge-base branchA branchC`    works :)